# DBSCAN detects outliers based on what ? and what are the criteria of the outliers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, outliers, dbscan

let's say I've this code

```
df= rn.read_sql(sql,conn)
data = df.as_matrix(['TOT_CLM_GROSS_AMT','Gross_Amt_per_SRV','TOT_CLM_NET_AMT'])
db = DBSCAN(eps=15, min_samples=200).fit(data)
```

and outliers are:

```
outliers_df= pd.DataFrame(data) 
outliers = outliers_df[db.labels_==-1]
```

can I know why DBSCAN consider outliers and what are their criteria? and can I know it by DBSCAN ?

Answer (score 3):

Noise is *not* the same as outliers.

Noise points are **low density points**. Formally, points where no neighbor point is dense enough (otherwise they would be border points).

The difference to outliers is this: **outliers are supposed to be *rare***. Depending on the parameters, **all points could be noise**.

Answer (score 1):

The DBSCAN algorithm is a *density* based algorithm. It looks at the *density* of data points in a neibourhood to decide whether they belong to the same cluster or not. If a point is too far from all other points then it is considered an outlier and is assigned a label of `-1`.

Basically you have a radius and a number of neighbours. The algorithms finds all points closer to radius to a given point and if they are greater than the number of neighbours it considers them as part of the same cluster as *core points*. You can also have *non-core points* cluster members, if they are closer than radius to a core point but their neighbourhood contains less than the specified number of neighbours.

The algorithm randomly starts checking these conditions on the data points, creating clusters and possibly merging close clusters together.

You can take a look at [wikipedia page on DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) or [this blog post](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-dbscan-works-and-why-should-i-use-it-443b4a191c80).

An other variation of the algorithm is HDBSCAN, which is the hierarchical version. There is an optimized python implementation called in the package `hdbscan` that you might want to try it out.

---

This said your question is probably better suited to [ComputerScience StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions) or one of the data-science related StackExchanges.